# drupal internal server error. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Tags: php, drupal

Now my site showing drupal internal server error.

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@xxxxxx.xx and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

There is no error reported in error log .

Comment: I don't think that's related to drupal, can you see your webserver logs? What's your webserver?

Comment: it was working fine 3 hours ago. I have other sites working smoothly in this domain with out any problem. Only this site showing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Betting on the fact you're using apache, please give the output of "locate error.log" on the server.
With luck you'll find the file containing your apache (and php by default) error log, you could then open it ("less /path/to/file") and get the last error.
Paste the error here and we'll have something to start with :)

Comment: there is no error reported in the error log. i just update my question

Comment: Two other things i think of: have you touched your .htaccess file, if not you could try anyway to put the original one in place of the present one. Or maybe the variable $base_url is not properly declared, it should reflect the base path of your drupal installation.

Answer (score 0):

**Internal Server Error

500 Internal Server Error is a generic error message, given when no more specific message is suitable. There are a number of causes for a 500 Internal Server Error to display in a web browser. Below is a sample error message**.

**`Internal Server Error`**[enter link description here](http://solveubuntu.blogspot.in/p/server.html)
Error with an .htaccess file
If you are using a .htaccess on your site, it may be interfering with the web page you are trying to load into your browser. Please double check the .htaccess configuration. Any syntax errors will cause a 500 Internal Server Error message to be displayed instead of your website.
To confirm whether a misconfiguration .htaccess is the cause of the 500 Internal Server error, either remove or rename the .htaccess file temporarily and then try to reload the page.